# php - Как в цикле foreach сделать вывод чисел перед моей строкой по порядку?

Tags: php

Есть вот такой цикл:

```
foreach ($pictures as $pict)
{
    echo "{$pict["name1"]}" . "{$pict["name2"]}" . "{$pict["name3"]}" .  "{$pict["name4"]}" . "\n";
 }
```

И вот такой массив:

```
$pictures = [["name1" => "name1"], ["name2" => "name2"], ["name3" => "name3"], ["name4" => "name4"]];
```

Я хочу, например, чтобы перед каждой новой строкой выводились числа по порядку от 1 до последнего значения. Как можно реализовать такую идею?

Comment: Добавить переменную-счетчик и на каждой итерации сначала ее выводить а потом увеличивать её на 1.

Comment: Это какой-то позор, что вопрос, что ответы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой пример:

```
foreach ($pictures as $i=>$pict)
{
    echo ($i+1).":"."{$pict["name1"]}"."{$pict["name2"]}"."{$pict["name3"]}"."{$pict["name4"]}"."\n";
 }
```

Формат разделения уже на ваше усмотрение. Я двоеточие поставил.

Comment: В foreach уже счётчик....такое не знать как-то стыдно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Исправил. Знать-то знаю, просто для простоты понимания так написал

Comment: только скорее всего будет $i + 1 (т.к. нужно отсчёт с 1), а так - уже лучше

Answer (score -1):

Такой вариант есть

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($pictures as $pict) {
    echo "{$i}. {$pict['name'.$i]}<br>";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: А счётчик самого foreach использовать религия не позволяет?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, задача была `чтобы перед каждой новой строкой выводились числа по порядку`. Они выводятся.

Comment: Ага, при задаче "забить гвоздь в деревянную доску" можно конечно использовать и собственный кулак и когда-нибудь гвоздь забьётся, только это неадкватно